# How do you auto initialize H2 db schema for Spring Boot sessions using JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

When I run my Spring Boot application it doesn't execute the schema.sql script. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

[Complete code here](https://github.com/victor-geere/demo2)

application.properties:

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=asdf

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

I have also tried adding this to my `application.properties`

```
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc')
  implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
  implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
  implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
  implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc')
  runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')
  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
  testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

schema.sql

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SPRING_SESSION;

  CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
  );

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
  CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
  CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

  CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES LONGVARBINARY NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

Spring version : 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after debugging your app, it seems to work normally, schema.sql got executed too but you need to have DEBUG level

add

> logging.level.root=DEBUG

and check out the logs:

[image]

Comment: Hi @slimane, I've already tried that and it made no difference. I'll edit my question and mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you switched off the hibernate ddl-auto option? If not put this in your application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Section 85.3 in the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) says

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema
>   or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.

Comment: thanks @pcoates, I also had to do this in the actual project

Answer (score 0):

You can use both hibernate auto-create and schema.xml, and you may need to use both, but they should not overlap.  If you declare a default schema for hibernate in `application.xml` as such:

```
spring:
 jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
      default_schema: NASA_SPACE_0
```

...hibernate does not create the schema NASA_SPACE_0, so `schema.xml` is the ideal place for this statement, and this works in conjunction with hibernate's ddl-auto creation:

```
create schema `NASA_SPACE_0`;
```